# Пес Барбос

Tags: этимология, ономастика

У домашних животных в русском языке есть устоявшиеся клички: кошка Мурка, кот Васька, корова Буренка, конь Орлик и т.д. Есть такие имена и для собак. Например, Шарик, Полкан (это имя тут уже обсуждалось), а еще - Барбос и Бобик.
Интуитивно я подозреваю, что происхождение эти имена ведут от иностранных. Например, в английском Боб - уменьшительное от Роберт (кстати, совершенно не понятно, как образом оно образовалось), Барбос - что-то испанское (и тут же вспоминается герой "Пиратов Карибского моря" капитан Гектор Барбосса). Так вот, как в простую русскую речь (а подобные клички в основном дают дворнягам в селах) попали иностранные имена собак и какое у них, имен, происхождение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Происхождение самое разное.  Вот здесь почитайте.

http://forum.alaskanmals.ru/index.php?topic=2010.0
http://www.biglik.ru/i-want-beagle/how-to-prepare/393-a-small-historical-and-linguistic-study

А Барбос - может быть иностранным, а может и простым стечением сочетаний-звукоподражаний. Фасмер не докопался до истоков, он пишет,что это распространенная собачья кличка (Крылов, Гоголь и др.). Сходство с румынским bărbós "бородатый", возможно, является чистой случайностью. (А возможно, и нет)
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/36598/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81

Но изначально так называли именно больших дворовых собак, может, кто-то назвал, а другой услышал, позаимствовал для похожей собаки.